# jqgrid obtener valores de una fila con radio button

Tags: jquery, radiobutton, jqgrid

tengo 3 filas en una grilla con jqgrid la primera es un radio button la segunda un código y la tercera un nombre, lo que necesito es rescatar el código de esa fila dependiendo de cual radio button este seleccionado, le di valores a la fila con la propiedad formatted y pese a que he probado varias soluciones entregadas acá no hay forma de que funcione, les dejo mi código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

PD: ya intente con este método: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552303/jqgrid-radio-button-select-single-row y me da error en el valor $grid (indica que no esta definido)

```js
$("#tblLocales").jqGrid({
   datatype: 'local',
   colNames:[
    ' ',
    'C&oacutedigo local',
    'Nombre local'
   ],
   colModel:[
    { name: 'select', label: 'select',align: "center", width: 50,
                         formatter: function radio(cellValue, option) {                          
                             return '<input type="radio" name="radio_' + option.gid + '" />';
                         } 
                     },
    {name:'CODIGO_LOCAL',index:'CODIGO_LOCAL',width:200,align:"left",sortable:false},
    {name:'NOMBRE',index:'NOMBRE',width:180,align:"left",sortable:false}
   ],
   xmlReader: {
    root: 'filas',
    row: 'fila',
    page: 'respuestaXML>paginaactual',
    total: 'respuestaXML>totalpaginas',
    records: 'respuestaXML>totalregistros',
    repeatitems: false,
    id: '[id]',
    userdata: "solemdata"
   },
   rowNum: 20,
   autowidth: true,
   multiselect: false,
   loadui: 'block',
   viewrecords: true,
   sortname: 'NOMBRE',
   sortorder: "asc",
   altRows: false,
   altClass: 'altRow',
   emptyrecords : '',

   loadComplete: function(xml) {
   },

   loadError: function(xhr,status,error){
    showAlert('Alerta', '(Locales Cliente) ' + error);
   }
 });
 
 
 
 // Obtener Valores
 
 $('#rdoLocales').click(function() {
     var radioSelec = $('input[name=rdoLocal' + $grid[0].id + ']:checked'), $tr;
        if (radioSelec.length > 0) {
            $tr = radioSelec.closest('tr');
             if ($tr.length > 0) {
                 codLocal = $tr.attr('id');
             }
        } else {
            alert("Porfavor seleccione una fila");
        }
    });
```

```html
<div id="divLocales" class="">
  <div class="row panel-body">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="divLocales" class="contenedor-grilla-documento-gestion">
     <table id="tblLocales"></table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: saludos podrias basarte en los ejemplos de jqgrid:http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/

Comment: selection->Get / Set selected row

Answer (score 0):

al final ocupe un metodo mucho mas simple, consiste en agregar al formatter un parámetro nuevo que contiene todo los valores del objeto, así a la misma fila se le da un value y se le pasa el valor de dicho objeto. les dejo el código:
`colModel:[
                { name: 'select', label: 'select',align: "center", width: 50,
                         formatter: function radio(cellValue, option , objRow) {

                         console.log(objRow.CODIGO_LOCAL);

                             return '<input type="radio" name="radio_' + option.gid + '" value="'+objRow.CODIGO_LOCAL+'" />';
                         } 
                     },
                {name:'CODIGO_LOCAL',index:'CODIGO_LOCAL',width:200,align:"left",sortable:false},
                {name:'NOMBRE',index:'NOMBRE',width:180,align:"left",sortable:false}
            ],`

y luego a una variable le asigne el valor de ese radio button.

```
var $grid = $("#tblLocales");

            var $selRadio = $('input[name=radio_' + $grid[0].id + ']:checked'), $tr;
            if ($selRadio.length > 0) {
                $selRadio.val();

                $tr = $selRadio.closest('tr');
                if ($tr.length > 0) {                           
                    var codLocal = $selRadio.val();
                }
            } else {
                alert("Favor seleccionar fila");
            }
            console.log(codLocal);
```